# Object doesn't support property or method 'replace' on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am trying to make my Vuejs application work on IE11. However, one node module (**vue-directive-tooltip**) throw an error on IE11:

**Object doesn't support property or methode "replace"**

The module is supposed to be IE11 compatible. I have tried to require the polyfill I need at the top of the entry point to my application. I have also tried to add the node module to the transpile dependencies.

vue.config.js:

```
require("@babel/polyfill");

configureWebpack: {
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main.js")],
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [ ">0.25%"]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "debug": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
};
```

I expect the vue-directive-tooltip to work on IE11, but the actual output is the following error message:

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'.**

Comment: Which object is it? What code line does the error come from? `replace` doesn't sound related to any babel-transpilation stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error comes from line 3050 from vueDirectiveTooltip.js :


**this2._$tpl.classList.replace(CSS.VISIBLE, CSS.HIDDEN);**

Comment: Ah, there we are. This has nothing to do with ES6, that code is using a DOM API not supported by IE11: [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility)[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace). You could shim it, but I'd recommend filing a bug against the plugin.

Comment: I have tested the [Vue Directive Tooltip online samples](https://hekigan.github.io/vue-directive-tooltip/#/usage), it also displays this error, so, this issue is related to the Vue Directive Tooltip plugin, you could feedback this issue to them. Besides, about this error, here is a [classlist ployfills](https://github.com/yola/classlist-polyfill), perhaps could solve the replace error, you could try to import it and use it. Also, you could try to add the [classList.js reference](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) in the index.html.

Comment: Adding the classList.js reference in the index.html was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the classList.js reference in the index.html was the solution.