# classList.replace() is not a method or property in IE11 after using babel-polyfill

Tags: javascript, html, polyfills

I have a web app that needs to support IE11. I am using ES6+ to code it and use babel-polyfill so it will be compatible with IE11. I have arrow functions, anonymous functions, and other ES6+ functionality working in IE11 with no problem. However, for some reason the element.classList.replace() method doesn't get polyfilled or something because IE11 can't seem to find it.

[MDN ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

So what I am trying to do is to get a list of html elements, loop every single element and replace a CSS class with another CSS class (pretty simple right?). Well, IE11 throws the following error "Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'. Thoughts?

Webpack version: 4.32.2,
@babel/core: 7.4.5,
@babel/polyfill: 7.4.4

Here is my JS:

```js
var invalidClassElement = document.querySelectorAll("[aria-owns*=".concat(id, "]"))[0].childNodes;
      invalidClassElement.forEach(function (node) {
        if (node.classList.contains('k-invalid')) {         
         
         node.classList.replace('k-invalid', 'k-default');
          
          // The code below works in IE11.
          // node.classList.remove('k-invalid');
          // node.classList.add('k-default');
        }
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

babel-polyfill does not polyfill classList, and classList support in IE11 is limited. You need an additional polyfill, as the link to MDN you provided also indicates.

Also see this existing answer:

[Object doesn't support property or method 'replace' on Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292355/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-replace-on-internet-explorer-11)

And a related core-js issue (which is used by babel-polyfill, so explains why it isn't implemented): https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/287

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but I made a polyfill that'll work on IE10-11. I needed one, but couldn't find one :(

```
DOMTokenList.prototype.replace = function (a, b) {
    var arr = Array(this);
    var regex = new RegExp(arr.join("|").replace(/ /g, "|"), "i");
    if (!regex.test(a)) {
        return this;
    }
    this.remove(a);
    this.add(b);
    return this;
}
```